# What does $S^3/\mathbb{Z}_k$ mean?

Tags: general-topology

It's just a quick question but I can't find it on Google and I don't know where in a topology book to look. $\mathbb{Z}_k$ is integers mod k. So how do I interpret $S$^3, the unit sphere in 4 dimensions, $\mod \mathbb{Z}_k$?

Comment: take a look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_3-manifold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the quotient of $S^3$ by a group action of $\mathbb Z/k$. One such action is obtained by realizing $S^3 \subseteq \mathbb R^4 = \mathbb C^2$, and $\mathbb Z/k \subseteq \mathbb C$ as the $k$th roots of unity. $\mathbb C^\times$ acts on $\mathbb C^2$ by scaling, and since $\mathbb Z/k \subseteq S^1$ the action preserves $S^3$.